# Rails - production.log file is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The production.log file is missing. I set my environment.rb file to:
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'production'

So it should be writing to a production.log file inside the log directory. Is there some kind of configuration I need to do to have it write to a production.log file?

I tried by creating a production.log file but it does not write to it.

Comment: Is it at least using the production db?

Answer (score 1):

Logging happens by default.

By the time Rails is running `environment.rb`, it could very well be too late to change the environment, and you're probably still in development. I'd recommend actually putting `RAILS_ENV=production` on the command you're using to boot the server.

Comment: I already have ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'production' inside my environment.rb file. Is there anyway else to get the logs to write to the production.log file while in production mode?